# CruiseControl .Net Plugin Vb.net Error

Tags: vb.net, plugins, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to make my own Labeller plugin for Cruise Control .Net 1.4.3.  I have made a class based on another plug in example but I keep getting an error

Class 'AssemblyVersionLabeller' must implement 'Function Generate(integrationResult As IIntegrationResult) As String' for interface 'ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.ILabeller'

Here is my code :

Imports Exortech.NetReflector
Imports ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core
Imports ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Util

Namespace NetAssembly.CCNet.Label
     _
    Public Class AssemblyVersionLabeller
        Implements ILabeller
        Public Sub Run(ByVal result As IIntegrationResult)
            result.Label = Generate(result)
        End Sub

```
    Public Function Generate(ByVal integrationResult As IIntegrationResult) As String
        Dim label As String = integrationResult.LastIntegration.Label

        Return label
    End Function

    <ReflectorProperty("prefix", Required:=False)> _
    Public Prefix As String = String.Empty

  End Class
```

End Namespace

What am I doing wrong?  What have I missed?

Background Info:

I am using VS2005.  I cant use CrusieControl 1.4.4 RC2 (which has an Assembly Labeller) because my source control's plugin (SCM Anywhere) doesnt work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot judge just by looking at your code, but if you need a sample on how to write labellers (C# code though), you could take a look at [BrekiLabeller](http://sourceforge.net/projects/brekiccnetutils/) code (written by me).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forgot the overrides decleration..

```
Public Overrides Function Generate
```